# How to send post json object in php?

Tags: php, json, post

I would to send Json object with post in php. How to send json object with post it. I have tried several posts in here but it is not working.

This is my code I have tried:

```
function get_user_post_other_count($user_id, $call_for)
{
    $params = array('user_id' => $user_id,
        'call_for' => $call_for);
// Build Http query using params
    $query = json_encode($params);

// Create Http context details
    $contextData = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n" . 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($query) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $query);
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $contextData));
    $result = file_get_contents(USER_PROFILE_COUNTER, false, $context);
    $json_decoded = json_decode($result, true);
    return $json_decoded;
}
```

Comment: Well show us a few things you have tried. Maybe it will also help us understand what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I have already edited above. You can see my code. Any help would be apperciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$context_options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
            'content' => json_encode($data)
            )
        );

$fp = fopen('http://url', 'r', false, $context_options);
```

Comment: I'd recommend using curl since it's much more reliable, but I thought you mentioned avoiding curl

Answer (score 2):

To send javascript obj to php using json and ajax:

js:

```
var dataPost = {
   "var": "foo"
};
var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataPost);

$.ajax({
   url: 'server.php',
   data: {myData: dataString},
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

to use that object in php:

```
   $obj = json_decode($_POST["myData"]);

    echo $obj->var;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Add this function in your php file :**

> ```
> <?php
>
> function do_post($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
>
>   $params = ['http' => ['method' => 'POST', 'content' => $data]];
>
>   if ($optional_headers !== null) {
>       $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
>   }
>
>   $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
>   $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
>
>   if (!$fp) {
>       throw new Exception("Exception caused with $url, $php_errormsg");
>   }
>
>   $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
>
>   if ($response === false) {
>       throw new Exception("Error reading response from $url, $php_errormsg");
>   }
>
>   return $response;
>
> }
> ```

**Step 2: Change your function accordingly**

```
function get_user_post_other_count($user_id, $call_for) {
    $params = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'call_for' => $call_for);    
    $query = json_encode($params);
    $response = do_post($url, $query);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

I would recommend `curl` here.

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP Curl
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

$ch = curl_init();

```
    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```